# Youtube video not showing in post

Tags: wordpress, genesis

When I published Youtube video post, that video not showing on page. I am using genesis sample theme to create my website. Is there any other way to show youtube video for genesis sample theme?

Comment: how are you adding the video to the page?

Comment: If you provide more information and a more specific question, you will increase your chances of receiving a quality response.

Comment: I am using Genesis framework. Here I created a custom page for showing my youtube blogs. When I create a post and paste the youtube link. The link show youtube video in visual edit mode. But once I published the post and view page, then the post show only title of the post and the content.

Comment: Also I am put this youtube video link in by default post but the result is same.

Comment: Process I followed: Copy the youtube url code and paste on my new post. Also I tried with embedded Iframe code but the result was same.

Comment: Can you give a link to your post, which does not work? Or it is not available in the internet?

Comment: No it is not available in the internet.

Comment: I am trying to reload my genesis theme and the sample theme.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with my blog (http://zlelik2000.wordpress.com/) and I used "Add Media" button and later I chose "Insert Youtube". You need to use link like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMZ28e6IQDE

Comment: I am using Genesis framework. Here I created a custom page for showing my youtube blogs. When I create a post and paste the youtube link. The link show youtube video in visual edit mode. But once I published the post and view page, then the post show only title of the post and the content.

Comment: You can try to put this code as well.

<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HMZ28e6IQDE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Also as I see there is some caching. You can try to press Ctrl+F5 in your browser to have real full refresh.

Comment: Not working. My custom page code here: //* Template Name: Youtube blog 

//* The blog page loop logic is located in lib/structure/loops.php

if(query_posts(array('post_type' => 'youblogs','paged' => $paged)));
genesis();

Comment: Is my Genesis theme sample theme file corrupted?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry you already told me but now I found 'Insert from URL'. Now I can see my youtube blog. Thanks again.